# Is there a Python interface like Windows Buider Editor in Eclipse?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to develop a Python program but I dont know much about UI. Do you know some UI editor like Windows Builder Editor or Java/Eclipse?

I want a tool like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuQow4uWm_g
but for Python.

Comment: Vote to close please. Save the poor guy the downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a couple of UI editor for use with python:

For pyqt or pyside(qt for python):
[QT disigner](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html)

GTK:
[Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: got it!! Glade is not for windows, but QT Disigner its looks for what i want a WYSIWYG thx men ill give it a try!!

Also if you know any other for windows let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're looking for someone to advise you on which IDE to use for Python.

Please see here - [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python?rq=1)

Comment: I see that post before i do my Question,
What i was asking for is a tool to design software like Windows Builder Editor plugin for eclipse to design jframe app...